# Sum values in text with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this ps code

```
PS > Select-String -path .\build-count-warn.txt -pattern "[1-9]?[0-9]+ warn"

warn.txt:1:    0 Warning(s)
warn.txt:2:    1 Warning(s)
warn.txt:3:    2 Warning(s)
```

..

So how to extend the ps script and report the sum of 0+1+2=3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capture the numeric value in the regex like so:

```
PS> "0 warnings","1 warnings","5 warnings" | Select-String "(\d+) warnings" | 
        Foreach {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value} | Measure -Sum


Count    : 3
Average  :
Sum      : 6
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

FYI I tested this on PowerShell V3 which supports member enumeration.  On V2, you may need to do this:

```
PS> "0 warnings","1 warnings","5 warnings" | Select-String "(\d+) warnings" | 
        Foreach {$_.Matches | Foreach {$_.Groups[1].Value}} | Measure -Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this, much faster:

```
  PS II>  $s="0 warnings","1 warnings","5 warnings" 
  PS II>  [regex]::matches($s,"(\d+)\s*warnings") | measure -inp {$_.Groups[1].Value} -sum
```